# Prepend region lines with given string

Tags: emacs, elisp, region

Emacs has a function called [`indent-region`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dline-Indent.html) and some similar functions, which insert some predefined string at the beginning of the lines within the selected region.

Instead, I want an interactive function that inserts a string given by user input at the beginning of the lines within the selected region. What emacs-lisp code can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to make use of a rectangle.

It's kind of difficult to present, but basically you can use `C-x r t` to insert a text on each line of a rectangle. You make a rectangle by starting with the pointer at, say, line 1, C-Space, move cursor down the amount of lines you want, and hit `C-x r t` following by entering the text.

Here's the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html).

Comment: @sawa You might find rectangle kill and yank to be useful as well!